# Request failed with status code '413' and status text 'Request Entity Too Large'

Tags: iis, visual-studio-lightswitch, http-status-code-413

With a 2013 Lightswitch html app while attempting to add a number of rows to a table with image data the server throws an error.  It can handle about 2Mb but after that it fails with the message

> Request failed with status code '413' and status text 'Request Entity
>   Too Large'

It does not seem to matter if I change the value in the web.config as follows

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the setting is maxReceivedMessageSize on the binding, just make it bigger (it's in bytes)

```
<webHttpBinding>
  <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600" />
</webHttpBinding>
```